# What Filesystem or raid-like structure can I use for broken / dying hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

Story: I have a 3TB Hard drive that is failing. I have recovered everything I want from it. Gradually, it is becoming more and more unusable as sectors on it become unstable (re-allocated sectors and unstable sectors are rising).

I would like to continue using this drive in some way instead of just wiping it and throwing it away. **I accept that this is unsafe and I can lose everything at any time.** I plan to use it for data that is entirely disposable, for example, software installers that can be re-downloaded at any time.

tl;dr
Is there some sort of filesystem or structure I can use to leverage some usability out of this drive? Perhaps something that has a builtin parity system or writes every bit to 2 parts of the drive independently behind the scenes? Ex. A Raid 1 mirror that uses 2 partitions on itself?

An immediate problem that I can see makes the drive too frustrating to use is if that FAT becomes corrupted the partitions don't mount anymore, so that also needs to be addressed somehow.

Comment: Sorry but a disk that is losing sectors continuously is really unusable.  The only way you could use it would be to pair it with another similar disk in RAID 1 which would only make it slower than your other disk.

Comment: If you do the RAID 1 on two partitions from the same disk, you still risk losing the partition table or getting corruption on both partitions.  It's simply unrecoverable.

Comment: I'd say try ZFS, but this really seems like a waste of time. After all, if you accept that you can lose everything, then why do you care so much about the FAT getting corrupted and unreadable anyway?

Comment: Because when the FAT is corrupted, I then have to manually intervene in order to keep reading or writing files to the drive. At that point, it's not worth bothering with it anymore. Having a drive with occasional file corruption is fine, but having to format a drive just to keep writing to it would go over the boundary of ridiculous.